# Action Function in APEX where is handler "onError"?

Tags: apex

The *apex:actionFunction* has *oncomplete* handler according to this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm. But I cannot find "onerror" handler in the list, or there are other patterns to handle exceptions from server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing, because an uncaught exception (e.g. an error) will cause the Visualforce screen of death:

[[image: Visualforce error]]

If you want more control over potentially fatal situations, consider using Remoting or actionFunctions instead; you should be able to use a normal try-catch block to catch and handle any exceptions you receive this way.